# how to use v-for for res.data return array with object keys?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, express

I'm trying to render a list getting the data returned by my api but it's being returned with object keys.

```js
getUserUrls() {
  const json = localStorage.getItem(userKey);
  const token = JSON.parse(json);

  axios
    .get('/urls/myurls', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      this.urls = res.data;
      console.log(this.urls);
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e.response.data));
},
```

```js
< div class = "url-content" v -for = "(url, i) in urls": key = "i" >
    {{urls.code}}
</div>
```

How do I access the data within this return?

res.data

```js
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(2)
0: {_id: '61afb389511285f26d203312', …}
1: {_id: '61afab1525d9048f7c5a844d', …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

Comment: What is the problem with current code exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to access the objects that are inside the response.data but when I try to access urls._id for example it returns undefined.

Comment: Sorry, I just solved it here realizing where I was wrong, I used {{urls[i]._id}} in v-for and it worked

Comment: It.s `url._id` then. `url` is `urls[i]`